# Manually configure Azure Active Directory with advanced settings B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Followed the tutorial/guide on "(Alternative method) Manually configure Azure Active Directory with advanced settings" and this allows us to use a different tenant AD for authentication. However can't access AD B2C. Is this possible?

Comment: The information in the question is insufficient. Can you please provide more detailed steps and/or error messages, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Accesing AD B2C: From your directory that has the subscription, you have to go to "Create Resource" on the top left of the page and then search for "Azure Active Directory B2C" (rather than searching for the resource in the search bar). At minimum you need an Azure Pay-As-You-Go subscription.

[image]

Then hit "Create"
[image]

After you hit "Create" you can select "Link an existing Azure B2C tenant to my subscription" and enter the tenant information for the directory where you would like the B2C AAD to exist.
[image]

Then it will deploy the b2c tenant to your resource group within your subscription.

[image]

Then follow the steps in the guide to register your application. You can deploy it under one tenant and register it under another.